# Entrypoint's exec form executed through shell

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I'm building a Windows based docker image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

# omitted for brevity

ENTRYPOINT ["c:\spinner.exe", "service", "w3svc", "-t", "c:\iislog\W3SVC\u_extend1.log"]
```

The base image sets the shell to `Powershell`:

```
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
```

My understanding was that when the exec form of the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction is used, the command will be executed without a shell. However, when I create the container, it fails with this error:

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 --isolation process --name pht site:local


$ docker logs pht

At line:1 char:77
+ ... ference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; [C:\\spin ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing ] at end of attribute or type literal.
At line:1 char:78
+ ... '; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; [C:\\spinner.exe, servic ...
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token ':\\spinner.exe' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:92
+ ... ; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; [C:\\spinner.exe, service ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EndSquareBracketExpectedAtEndOfAttribute
```

And when I inspect the stopped container, I see the executed command was through shell:

```
 "Entrypoint": [
                "powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; [\"c:\\spinner.exe\", \"service\", \"w3svc\", \"-t\", \"c:\\iislog\\W3SVC\\u_extend1.log\"]"
            ],
```

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *exec* syntax requires JSON format, which means that `\` instances in the array elements must be escaped as `\\`.

**Since your `ENTRYPOINT` instruction therefore does not contain a valid JSON array, it looks like Docker is falling back to *shell* syntax** and therefore passes your `ENTRYPOINT` argument to the shell, which in your case is PowerShell, as defined in your `SHELL` instruction - and that **results in a *broken shell command*.**<sup>[1]</sup>

**A syntactically correct `ENTRYPOINT` in *exec* format - i.e., valid JSON - *prevents* involvement of a shell, which is the correct approach in this case**, given that your command contains *literal* elements only.

Therefore, try the following (`\` instances escaped as `\\`):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["c:\\spinner.exe", "service", "w3svc", "-t", "c:\\iislog\\W3SVC\\u_extend1.log"]
```

That way, Docker should end up executing the following command line in the container:

```
c:\spinner.exe service w3svc -t c:\iislog\W3SVC\u_extend1.log
```

---

<sup>[1] What happens is that the malformed `ENTRYPOINT` argument, `["c:\spinner.exe", "service", "w3svc", "-t", "c:\iislog\W3SVC\u_extend1.log"]`, is taken to be a *single* argument - a *verbatim string* to be escaped based on JSON rules (doubling of `\` chars.)  - to be passed to the *shell*, as defined by your `SHELL` instruction. This means appending that argument to the last argument of your `SHELL` array, preceded by a space character. What you saw in the logs is evidence of that.</sup>

Comment: You're right! It didn't occur to me that backslashes in Json were the problem. I even changed the escape character for the Dockerfile to backtick thinking that'll propagate to the command, but it doesn't.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, @AmirKeibi. My _guess_ is that the configurable escape character only applies to _unquoted_ arguments and line-continuation.